# How do I get the expression of a CHECK constraint using TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following statement will return all the CHECK constraints.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'CHECK'
```

How do I get the expression? For example, I want to see the actually constraint, such as `([ApplicationId]=(8))`, being applied to a table.

Thanks!

SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT tc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME, tc.TABLE_NAME, cc.CHECK_CLAUSE
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[CHECK_CONSTRAINTS] cc
     INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc 
       ON  cc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
       AND cc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = tc.TABLE_SCHEMA
```

Comment: You might want to add tc.TABLE_NAME in the select.  Otherwise, there's no need to join to tc.